# persisting an array using a foreach loop

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to persist several items to the database using doctrine, but only the last item is being persisted. So instead of having rows of all the array items I only get the last row persisted in the database. I have tried several ways but they still persist only one item, the first or the last. What am I doing wrong. Here is my new code. I edited some stuff and tried some other stuff but the problem still persists.

```
foreach ($options as $option)
{
     $pollOption = new PollOption();
     $pollOption->setName($option);
     $pollOption->setPoll($pollData);
     $em->persist($pollOption);
     $em->flush();          
 }
```

when i use the above foreach loop it only commits the last pollOption in the loop and a single pollData item in the database.

when i use the foreach loop below it commits all the pollOptions in the loop but also commits a new row of pollData in each loop. Thus i end up having multiple rows of the same pollData each associated with a single option in the foreach.

foreach ($options as $option)

{

$pollOption = new PollOption();

$pollOption->setName($option);

$pollOption->setPoll($pollData);

$em->persist($pollOption);

$em->flush();

$em->clear();

}

Here is the rest of the code for PollOption and the PollData
pollData class code showing the mapping:
class Poll

{

/**

- @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PollOption", mappedBy="poll")

*/

protected $poll_options;

```
/**

 * Add poll_options

 *
 * @param \Spidd\InformationBundle\Entity\PollOption $pollOptions
 * @return Poll
 */
public function addPollOption(\Spidd\InformationBundle\Entity\PollOption $pollOptions)
{
    $this->poll_options[] = $pollOptions;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove poll_options
 *
 * @param \Spidd\InformationBundle\Entity\PollOption $pollOptions
 */
public function removePollOption(\Spidd\InformationBundle\Entity\PollOption $pollOptions)
{
    $this->poll_options->removeElement($pollOptions);
}

/**
 * Get poll_options
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getPollOptions()
{
    return $this->poll_options;
}
```

}

PollOption Class:

class PollOption

{

```
/**

 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Poll", inversedBy="poll_options", cascade={"all"})

 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="poll_id", referencedColumnName="id")

 */

protected $poll;
/**
 * Set poll
 *
 * @param \Spidd\InformationBundle\Entity\Poll $poll
 * @return PollOption
 */
public function setPoll(\Spidd\InformationBundle\Entity\Poll $poll = null)
{
    $this->poll = $poll;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get poll
 *
 * @return \Spidd\InformationBundle\Entity\Poll 
 */
public function getPoll()
{
    return $this->poll;
}
```

}

Above is my new code. I want persist several pollOptions mapped to a single pollData object. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you persisting them every time the loop iterates? It could also cause memory overflow at a certain time. You might want to add them to a batch of specific number of items and then persist the batch to the database. **Disclaimer :** I'm familiar with JPA/Hibernate but I never used doctrine.

Comment: NOt sure if it'll work, but how about setting $polloption to null on each loop

Comment: No experience with dotrine but shouldn't the pollData be inside of the pollOption object. Might be that the second persist call is in error

Comment: i have tried persisting the pollData from the pollOption object using cascading but the problem doesn't dissappear. The major isue is that it commits only one pollOption item when it loops, the last one, so it's like it's overwriting whatever item that was persisted before it thus i end up having only one row in the database instead of multiple rows of all the pollOptions for each loop.

Comment: You should share the code of PollOption; the problem most likely lies in there.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your help. Above is the updated version of the code but it still doesn't work. I would really much appreciate your suggestions. Lion i want to be able to persist each first so that when it works then i can persist them in a batch. Thomas I can't set the pollOption to null because i want to persist it's data to the database. Orangepill and TML i have added the code for PollOption and pollData.